# How do i get the element of a specific input value?

Tags: jquery

I have the element `.tousers`, which  is an input text field with the value `car`.

```
if($("#compose-child-container-1").find(".tousers").val()=="car") {

                                    }
```

I want to `addClass` to that `.tousers` element but how do i select it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward solution would be to look in each `.tousers` element

```
$("#compose-child-container-1 .tousers").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'car') $(this).addClass('className');
});
```

*Note:* `[value="car"]` will not work for user-modified values. Hence the loop is pretty much the only solution.

Comment: You can still use `filter()` instead of an explicit loop.

Comment: okay. So it may work only if value is car when the page first loads?

Comment: @OptimusPrime - yes. It won't work for user-input values. For values loaded into the DOM, it will work.

Comment: @DennisMartinez - Check http://jsfiddle.net/L7CfN/2/ - Now type "car" into the first textbox.

Answer (score 3):

Here the attribute selector will not work since once the user modifies the value in the input field the attribute is not updated, only the dom elements property is updated

What I would do is

```
$("#compose-child-container-1").find(".tousers").filter(function(){
    return this.value == 'car'
}).addClass('someclass')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)`. In your function, you should use `$(selector).each(function() { // code }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#compose-child-container-1 .tousers').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.val() == 'car') {
        el.addClass('found');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("#compose-child-container-1 .tousers").filter(function() {
    return this.value == "car";
}).addClass('found');
```

This separates the logic to find the elements from what you actually want to do with them (addClass in this instance).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#compose-child-container-1").find(".tousers").each(function(){
if($(this).val()=='car'){
$(this).addClass('className');
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure there's at most one `.tousers` element:

```
var $_tousers = $('#compose-child-container-1 .tousers');
if ($_tousers.val() == 'car') $_tousers.addClass('found');
```

If there's more than one, though, the class will be set on all of them if the first one's value is 'car', regardless of the others' values.

Or, if you feel like getting spiffy about it, you could create a custom selector to test against an element's current value.

```
$.expr[':'].value = function(obj, index, meta, stack) {
    console.log(meta);
    var candidateValue = meta[3];
    return (candidateValue === $(obj).val());
};

...

$('#compose-child-container-1 .tousers:value(car)').addClass('found');
```

Though this requires building a new selector to test for a different value.

Or, you could have a plugin.

```
$.fn.withVal = function(val) {
    return this.filter(function() { return this.value == val; });
}

...

$('#compose-child-container-1 .tousers').withVal('car').addClass('found');
```

Note, extending jQuery (either with custom selectors or plugins) is only really worthwhile if you're going to want to use it a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it's quick and clean:

```
$("#compose-child-container-1").find(".tousers").filter(function () { 
   return this.value === 'car';
}).addClass('your-class');
```